# Pass url parameter in a switch case in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a parameter in a URL and based on this parameter I created a switch statement in javascript to call a specific function that will trigger a Jenkins job.

The URL looks like this: `http://localhost:8000/user/build-trigger/?job=data1`

My code looks like this :

```
$(function(){
        init_build_trigger();
    })

    function init_build_trigger(){
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search) ;

    switch (urlParams) {

        case "data1":
            $.getJson("/model-api/jenkins/build_for_data1/",function(data){
        })
        break;

    case "data2":
            $.getJson("/model-api/jenkins/build_for_data2/",function(data){
        })
        break;
           }

    console.log(urlParams.get('job')) ;
    }
```

The build function looks like this :

```
 def build_for_data1(self, request):
        url = "jenkins url "
        response = requests.get(url)
        result = None
        if response:
            result = "started successfully."
        else:
            result = "failed. An error has occurred."    
        return Response(result)
```

When I access the link nothing is happening, the job is not triggered.
Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: "data1" is string, not a `URLSearchParams` object. You might be able to do it with `switch (urlParams.get("job"))`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) it returns a Map object you can iterate through.

So you need to use this in the following way

```js
switch (urlParams.get('job')) {
 ...
}
```